# System cannot find file `inetmgr.exe`

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to run the file `inetmgr.exe` so I can deploy a webservice, but I cannot seem to find it.

I have visual studio 2012 installed, and when it installed, it also installed the iis express 8 with it. However, `start->run->inetmgr.exe` produces an error message as the system does not find the file.

I am very much a beginner, so I apologize if my answer is stupid, and thank any potential answerers for all their patience...

Comment: Have you installed IIS on your computer? If not follow these steps http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7

Comment: As I said, I have visual studio 2012 installed, and when it installed, it also installed the iis express 8 with it. In the control panel, `IIS 8.0 express` is indeed listed as one of the programs installed.

Comment: Follow the link and install it. Then start->run->inetmgr.exe it will come

Comment: IIS Express is intended for running your website in Visual Studio. It's not intended for running deployed websites -- see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2562885. I doubt that it includes inetmgr.exe.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Thank you, I guess. It is the answer I needed, if not the one I wanted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inetmgr.exe is the exe of the regular IIS.

You need the iisexpress.exe. Have you looked at http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-80-express-readme?

Do you need to start that to configure some settings? If so, the link I provided should help you out.